# Drupal 7 image_style_url not creating the styled image

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

I have the following codes to test the image_style_url() on the latest drupal(v7.59)

```
<img src=“<?= file_create_url($fileuri); ?>” />
<img src=“<?= image_style_url(“medium”, $fileuri); ?>” />
```

The file_create_url() can show the original image properly, and the image_style_url() can only give the styled image url, but not creating any styled image in the styled image folder.

the public://  and the /tmp directriea are in 777 permission setting, so it won’t be related to permission problem.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have to create the image derivate first. Normally this happens automatically when uploading an image via an image field upload. But the automatic derivate creating might simply get skipped on file field uploads, or when using some other image which isn't managed by Drupal at all, or when you added an image style after you already uploaded the image.

Have a look at [`image_style_create_derivative($style, $source, $destination)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_style_create_derivative/7.x). Check out the comments as well as `$style` needs to be an array returned by `image_style_load('MYSTYLE')`.

> Creates a new image derivative based on an image style.

Only issue left open is how to check first if the derivate already exists before calling that function. Maybe you can check what `file_exists(image_style_path($style_name, $file_uri))` returns, first.

---

Read more: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/22555/15055

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with your Drupal. Derivative image is not physically created until someone visits the listing where that style is used.

Example: You create new node and upload an image on it. Original image is within files folder. But if you use for example teaser image style and if you go to teaser folder the image is not created there until someone visits the page where "teaser" image style is used. You can easily test this on clean Drupal. Basically the image is created on the fly on HTTP request.

Comment: I did test the code in a browser. And the image_style_url() didn't create any styled image

Comment: of-course it didn' t and that is what I've told you in a previous comment.  To generate derivates instantly on image upload instead of on HTTP request use Imageinfo Cache module. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache